# How to close my connection which is automatically created by Visual studio when I drag and drop my table from data source

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have dropped `dataGridView` on `form1` from my data source it automatically connect my form with my database,

I close this `form1` and in `form2` I want to copy my data base from one directory to other as a backup by using IO copy.

When I select my db file using open file dialog it says file is being used by other application, I give static path to copy function of IO class but it again give exception that file is being used,

On `form2` I am not using any db link if I directly open `form2` on application start it will copy db file, but if I open once `form1` from `form2`, form will connect with db and then from `form1` I go to `form2` now it will not open my db file or give exception.

I used all methods in my `form1` dispose and GC to release my db file but use less.

Tell me how to release db file my `form1` is closed db file is only linked with `form1`,

Tell me where visual studio create connection in drag and drop case so that I may close my connection on form closing or

Tell me some other way to release my db file

Answer (score 0):

From the View menu, select Server Explorer. This window will show you any connections to databases that Visual Studio knows of and are connected to. You should be able to close VSs connection to the database in this window.

Comment: you didn't get me i want to close my connection through coding. when i close my form1 and switch to form2 at run time

Comment: My apologies. I was under the impression that Visual Studio itself was maintaining a connection to the database which was stopping you from moving or altering it. Could you please post some sample code. That would make supplying an answer a bit easier. Thanks.

Comment: this is the problem that i cant get that code which visual studio created itself while dropping the table on to my form1. If i came to know that what is my object of connection which VS created i would b able to close it